# What does 下界の結果 mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> ま、俺達にとっちゃ
>   どっちでもいいことさ。
>   ただ指示されたままのことをする。
>   上の意向も下界の結果も関係ない。

Context - Soldiers argue about their mission.

> 上の意向も下界の結果も関係ない.

My attempt - The opinion of higher-ups
and the consequences on
the ground are irrelevant.

Comment: You have pretty much answered your own question.

Comment: `The opinion of higher-ups and the consequences on the ground are irrelevant.` -- My brain automatically interpreted it as "The opinion of higher-ups and the consequences on the ground are irrelevant *to us / to our mission / to what we do*", but..  was it meant to say "The opinion of higher-ups and the consequences on the ground are unrelated to each other"?

Answer (score 1):

下界 means earthly (as opposed to heavenly) i.e. material, mundane. 
結果 means consequences, results, or fruits (of labor etc.)

So in this context, I would probably translate 下界の結果 as material consequences. Your translation "consequences on the ground" is more colloquial though so given the slang in the way this is written, I'd say it's pretty spot on!

Answer (score 0):

> The opinion of higher-ups and the consequences on the ground are irrelevant.

Your attempt is incorrect, because "上の意向も下界の結果も関係ない" means "俺達のやること（the soldiers' mission）は上の意向と関係ない、そして、俺達のやることは下界の結果とも関係ない".

**EDIT**: In other words the given phrase "上の意向も下界の結果も関係ない" means "俺達にとっちゃ上の意向も俺達には関係ない、また、下界の結果も俺達には関係ない".

If your attempt were correct, the original Japanese phrase should be as:
上の意向と下界の結果は関係ない。 Neither of the も's in the phrase is needed.

## EDIT 2

> ま、俺達にとっちゃ
> どっちでもいいことさ。
> ただ指示されたままのことをする。
> 上の意向も下界の結果も関係ない。

は、次のような意味です。

> ま、俺達にとっちゃ どっちでもいいことさ。
> 俺たちは、ただ上から指示されたままのことをするだけさ。
> そのとき、どういう意向で上の人が指示を出しているか知らないし、知りたくもない。
> だから、俺達にとっちゃ上の意向も関係ないし、その（＝俺達が指示されたままのことをやった）結果、下界がどうなろうと俺達にとっちゃ関係ない。

ですから、ＯＰの attempt である "The opinion of higher-ups and the consequences on the ground are irrelevant." は、ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ さんのコメントにある "The opinion of higher-ups and the consequences on the ground are irrelevant **to us / to our mission / to what we do**" と native speaker of English がゴシック体で示した文言を自然に補って解釈できるのでなければ間違いでしょう。

Comment: I guess there's no contradiction between my version and your explanation. By "The opinion of higher-ups and the consequences on the ground are irrelevant", in the given context I meant 
"We just follow instructions and don't care about opinion of higher-ups and the results of our actions on the ground"

Comment: OPってどういう意味ですかね？

Comment: @ajsmart 通常は、Original Post または Original Poster の意味で使われていると思います

Comment: @Guest: ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆさんのコメント欄での質問にGuestさんが答えていないので私も、「ゴシック体で示した文言を自然に補って解釈できるのでなければ」と注記を入れた上で間違いと書きました。日本語ではǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆさんや私の推察どおりの意味の補完がありますが、英語でも同じであることが分かりました。ありがとうございました。なお、コメントで質問があればそれに答えるのは質問者の義務だと思います。